# Sending ESC/POS command to printer using serial port

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I have a thermal printer. and I am re-writing the SDK.
I am using pi4j library to send ESC/POS commands through the serial port.
my problem is I do not know how to send integer to the printer since the pi4j    library does not accept integer

This is my function

```
public void printAndFeed(String str, int feed) throws IOException {
    //escInit();
    serial.write(str);
    //output extra paper          ESC d n
    serial.write((char) 0x1B);
    serial.write("d");
    serial.write(feed);
}
```

the Error is here

```
serial.write(feed);
```

And the command reference:

> ESC d n [Name] Print and feed n lines [Format] ASCII ESC d n Hex 1B 64
>   n Decimal 27 100 n [Range] 0≤n≤255 [Description] Prints the data in
>   the print buffer and feeds n lines. [notes] •This command sets the
>   print starting position to the beginning of the line. •This command
>   does not affect the line spacing set by ESC 2 or ESC 3. •The maximum
>   paper feed amount is 1016 mm {40"}. If the paper feed a mount (n× line
>   spacing) of more than 1016 mm {40"} is specified, the printer feeds
>   the paper only 1016 mm {40"}. [Reference] ESC 2(default line
>   spacing)，ESC 3(set line spacing)

the pi4j reference
http://pi4j.com/apidocs/com/pi4j/io/ser ... e-char...-

I tried this one:
The code can accept:

```
            char[] F = new char[]{0x1B,'d',11};
            serial.write(F);
```

but it does not accept this

```
            char[] F = new char[]{0x1B,'d',feed};
            printer.write(F);
```

Comment: does the `write()` method have a version that accepts `byte[]` ?

Comment: I agree with what @Yazan said: you should be sending bytes (via an `OutputStream` type of interface) rather than char/String (via a `Writer`). The link that you posted to the pi4j reference is broken, so I can't tell if this is possible.

Comment: yes the writer accept byte[]
and this is the working link: http://pi4j.com/apidocs/com/pi4j/io/serial/SerialDataWriter.html

Comment: @Yazan I have tried byte, and no errors. do you this the code is correct?
                 byte [] B1=new byte[] {0x1B,'d',(byte)feed};
                printer.write(B1);

Comment: yes Ammar, i think that's how you need to send the commands, just make sure the 'd' is correctly converted to byte, otherwise i recommend using `"d".getBytes()` and insert it into ur `B1` array

Comment: and the most important question, did it work as intended? i mean did it "print the data and feed" the paper?

Comment: The printer is not with me write now, i will try it when i finish the code and get back to the office. @Yazan thanks again

Answer (score 1):

@Yazan,@Mike Harris  Thank you so much for your help.
I converted all my integer to byte as they suggested
the code is (if someone came across this and needed help)

`int feed=11;
byte [] B=new byte[] {0x1B,'d',(byte)feed};
printer.write(B);`